# circleci config.yml: 'Invalid template path template.yml'

Tags: devops, pipeline, circleci, circleci-workflows

I am working on a CI/CD project(Using circleci pipeline) and currently, I am stuck on getting my "create_infrastructure" job to work. Below is the job

```
    # AWS infrastructure
    create_infrastructure:
          docker:
              - image: amazon/aws-cli
          steps:
            - checkout
            - run:
                name: Ensure backend infrastructure exist
                command: |
                  aws cloudformation deploy \
                    --template-file template.yml \
                    --stack-name my-stack
```

When I run the job above, it returns `Invalid template path template.yml`

- Where am I suppose to keep the `template.yml` file?
- I placed it in the same location as the `config.yml` in the project's GitHub repository(**Is this right?**)
- Could the problem on the line `--template-file template.yml` in my job? (**I am a beginner here**).
  Please I need help.

Comment: Can someone help me out?

Comment: It's error because the job could not find the template.yml path. Just set the working_directory and specify the file name, which should work.

Comment: @karikevinod, what should be the working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually misspelled the name of the template found in my GitHub repository. Everything worked well after I correct it.
But I think this error was not explicit at all, I was expecting something like 'template not found in the path specified', instead of 'Invalid template path template.yml'

Comment: ditto! i did .yaml instead of .yml :)